# Can't resolve all parameters for NgxGalleryPreviewComponent after ng serve

Tags: angular

I recently updated my angular project from version 8 to 9 and have been experiencing the above mentioned issue. My project makes use of `ngx-gallery` and after the update to angular 9, I updated all references to the deprecated `Renderer` service to `Renderer2` inside `ngx-gallery-helper.service.d.ts` and `ngx-gallery-preview.component.d.ts`.

My currently installed version of `npx-gallery` is the latest one (5.10.0). When I run `ng serve` the home page doesn't even load, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NgxGalleryPreviewComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?, [object Object]).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2281)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:21063)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:20958)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:20573)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:20437)
    at compiler.js:26467
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:26466
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:26463)
```

Running `ng --version` inside my project root folder outputs the following:

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.1
Node: 12.8.0

Angular: 9.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.900.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.900.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.900.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.900.1
@angular-devkit/core               9.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics         9.0.1
@angular/cli                       9.0.1
@angular/flex-layout               9.0.0-beta.29
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                   9.0.1
@schematics/angular                9.0.1
@schematics/update                 0.900.1
rxjs                               6.5.4
typescript                         3.7.5
webpack                            4.41.2
```

What am I missing? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you are missing one of the dependency injections. The 4th service is not in any module.

Comment: [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?, [object Object]) that "?" is one service in the constructor of the class that's not correctly injected.

Comment: I see that. The problem is that I don't quite understand why that service is missing. Before the update the module was working fine. The module initially made references to the now deprecated Renderer service but after the move to angular 9, I updated the references in the module's code to Rendere2 and then I got that error. That 4th service missing is the renderer service.

Comment: @NelsonKing How did you fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files "ngx-gallery-helper.service.d.ts" and "ngx-gallery-preview.component.d.ts" are inside folder node_modules. Node_modules generated automatically with npm. No changes inside folder 'node_modules' possible. It will be recreated with npm.

Solution of bug must be not very hard. As usual. Change "Renderer" -> "Renderer2" and related items. But really big problem - this gallery in repository and only author of ngx-gallery has got access.

What can be done:

- Trigger author of https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-gallery. Ask him to fix bug and push fix into repository.
- Move gallery from repository to local module and fix bug. Before this better to try fix files "ngx-gallery-helper.service.d.ts" and "ngx-gallery-preview.component.d.ts" in "node_modules" by hands and look if problem was gone. Just for test.
- Rewrite "ngx-gallery-helper.service.d.ts" and "ngx-gallery-preview.component.d.ts" in your app. But future possible update of ngx-gallery will cause problems.
- Use other gallery or write your own.

BTW https://github.com/thatisuday/ngx-image-gallery works well with Angular 9. Just checked. And good customisation.